# Gitlab-CI: how to pass variable to a upstream

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have two parts in my ci job :

1. Base part:

```
 .base:
      image: <image_name>
      script:
       -| 
        my_command <VAR_NAME>
```

2. extending part:

```
.develop:
 extends: .base
 variables:
   VAR_NAME: "MY_VAR"
```

How can I do this in gitlab? In summary I want to pass a variable "VAR_NAME"  from extended function (".develop") and pass to extended function(".base")?

Comment: sooo just `$VAR_NAME`? `How can I do this in gitlab?` You can do this exactly how you posted it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass variables between gitlab-ci jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71307114/how-to-pass-variables-between-gitlab-ci-jobs)